# Not Getting Syslog messages After Reload of logstash pipeline

Tags: logstash, syslog, logstash-configuration

My logstash pipeline accepts Syslog messages at defined port and there are two log syslog sources for sending messages to this pipeline . So when I change the configuration pipeline , the new Changed configuration is loaded and pipeline restarts but after that it is listening on the same port for syslog messages and it doesn't receive any syslog messages while my syslog sources still continue sending the syslog messages.  I don't want to restart syslog sources after reload of pipeline. Why I cant recieve the Syslog messages?

Comment: To many question in one question

Comment: I asked only one question